# The MMSE Sandbox

Tags: discussion

Similar to [this sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3132/19538), you're encouraged to write drafts of your questions here before posting them on the main site, if you think this may be beneficial. I was tempted to come up with a set of "rules" for this, or to simply say "don't over use this", but my guess is that this won't be necessary. Also, if you "over use" this, bringing more traffic into our Meta site might not be such a bad thing :)

If you have an answer to any of these questions, please leave a comment and the question can be moved from The MMSE Sandbox to the main site, if the asker wishes.

Answer (score 0):

## Who was JK Cashion?

Searching "JK Cashion" in Google seems to result in nothing but papers. I cannot even find his or her first name!

However JK Cashion remains legendary in the field of diatomic spectroscopy due to his seminal papers in the 1960s on numerically solving the Schroedinger equation to get the energies and wavefuncions of vibrational and rotational states of molecules with potentials that are more realistic than the very simple ones for which the problem is solvable analytically.

JK Cashion was mentioned in the Nobel Prize lecture of John Polyani (see [this PDF](https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/polanyi-lecture.pdf)). [Polanyi's official website](http://sites.utoronto.ca/jpolanyi/profile/profile2.html) also mentions JK Cashion, saying that Cashion was Polanyi's graduate student and that their two-author [1958 paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1744517) introduced a method that "promises to provide for the first time information concerning the distribution of vibrational and possibly rotational energy among the products of a three-center reaction" which was then realized about a decade later, after the "work of a substantial group of graduate students". Interestingly, [Google Scholar provides a citation](https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.bib?q=info:UazE8jesW-wJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisdr=CgUtH4A1EMa8zZnFXWA:AAGBfm0AAAAAYxfDRWAjMW0wt4u3r4wxQP39BDcmQEKZ&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAYxfDRWwxMATkt2NNJnsnym-JxW_3oDMz&scisf=4&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=en) to Cashion's PhD thesis from 5 years earlier (**and 2 years before Polanyi joined that university**, see [this PDF](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ar50053a001?casa_token=UOWAD70CKJUAAAAA:wBetg4q_Lxq3XIJ4NCwPkpHXkOxLlEuq8BQuGRI7Sbd18v4rurrhiACrqUOejQ5jiulRmo5rImTgFd_s)). It would appear from his two-author paper with [Donald James LeRoy](https://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/donald-james-le-roy)  (father of [Robert J. Le Roy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_J._LeRoy)), published 1 year after the 1953 PhD thesis (see [this PDF](https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v54-115?download=true)) that he did a first PhD with DJ LeRoy followed by becoming a grad student of Polanyi. Maybe Google Scholar has erroneously called his Bachelors or Masters level thesis of 1953 a PhD thesis, but in any case I was eventually able to find [his 1960 PhD thesis](https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.bib?q=info:ansF2dWir4MJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisdr=CgUtH4A1EMa8zZnBpbA:AAGBfm0AAAAAYxfHvbCuSA44aPoaNpzq84MmsrrAaZhD&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAYxfHvYOUeK1oVGURH175AYQI6wt87YjH&scisf=4&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=en) (which also finally gives his full name: John Kenneth Cashion!). Searching "John Kenneth Cashion" basically gives 1 new hit, which is [a black-and-white picture of a professor emeritus at University of Wisconsin-Parkside](https://archives.uwp.edu/exhibits/show/uwp_photos/item/2379#?c=0&m=0&s=0&cv=0&xywh=0%2C-508%2C2821%2C2821) but not much more.

After a [1961 paper with Polanyi](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1731976), Cashion seems to have joined the "Aeronical Research Laboratories" where he completed a [solo-author technical report in 1962](https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.bib?q=info:U8qNtXklNKIJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisdr=CgUtH4A1EMa8zZnP1_A:AAGBfm0AAAAAYxfJz_Dn-3FJ3d6n2902ep3sPNOCnmWt&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAYxfJz9B4SPucb7dGj6HQfRLYYtEHXkDC&scisf=4&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=en), followed by a move to what is now called the [Lawrence Berkeley National Lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Berkeley_National_Laboratory) where in 1963 he published papers by himself and with Nobel Prize winner [Dudley Herschbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudley_R._Herschbach)'s then-PhD-student [Ricahrd Zare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Zare) and then a papers with Herschbach himself in 1964 including an empirical potential energy surface for H3 which has been described as the [Cashion-Herschbach potential in the **title** of a paper as recently as 2000](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0009261400009180).

When Herschbach (and Zare) moved to Harvard, it looks like Cashion came along too. Cashion and Herschbach have a 1964 [paper together with Berkeley affiliation](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1725515) and also a 1964 [paper together with Harvard affiliation](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1726230), but then he stopped publishing with them and instead did an intermolecular potential for (H<sub>2</sub>)<sub>2</sub> [published in 1965](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1726805) with Nobel Prize winner Van Vleck's Harvard PhD student Roy Gordon, followed by three solo-author papers with Harvard affiliation in 1966 ([here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1727809), [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1727810), and [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1727655)), seemingly nothing in 1967, then a solo-author [1968 paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1667995) with IBM Waston Lab affiliation.

I'm not able to find any 1969 papers by Cashion, but at IBM he published 4 papers with Dean E. Eastman and others from 1970-1971 including **three** in PRL! But Cashion's career publishing in scientific journals seems to have ended in 1971, Dean Eastman continued publishing until [this seemingly final 1988 Science paper](https://www.science.org/doi/abs/10.1126/science.241.4868.936) and [went on to become a very successful executive at IBM and then the Arognne National lab](https://history.aip.org/phn/11507021.html) (part of a pattern of success with Cashion's other collaborators: Nobel Prize winners Polanyi and Herschbach, extremely successful professors Zare and Gordon, and high-ranking executives LeRoy and Eastman), but Cashion seems to have fallen off the visible record after 1971.

---

After referring to some of the original papers (including Cashion's) on solving the Schroedinger equation to get rovibrational energies and wavefunctions of diatomic molecules, and not being able to find anything (not even a first name!) in a Google search, I felt like asking "who was JK Cashion?" here. In my requisite research prior to posting, I was able to trace his life from Toronto to Berkeley to Harvard to IBM, who he worked with, and when he published (almost exclusively through Google Scholar and looking at actual ***papers***), but I wonder if someone who knows better might be able to write a biography of him in an answer here?

Comment: You'll find more references to "Ken Cashion, including on Dudley Herschbach's [list of former group members](https://faculty.chemistry.harvard.edu/dudley-herschbach/pages/former-group), as well as in a couple of Herschbach's writings https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201610968 https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.physchem.51.1.1 Polanyi also referred to him as Ken in some old [autobiographical notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20121014130558/https://www.utoronto.ca/jpolanyi/profile/profile3.html) that mention Ken was his first grad student.

Comment: [Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20010505233408/http://www.uwp.edu/academic/chemistry/chemfac/cashion.html) a version of Cashion's old website that lists his different appointments, and [here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20050618075343/http://oldweb.uwp.edu/academic/chemistry/chemfac/cashion.html) a later version that removes most of the information but has a photo and mentions his emeritus status.

Comment: And [here's a 2014 obituary](https://web.archive.org/web/20160320034614/https://journaltimes.com/news/local/history-professor-oliver-hayward-was-a-favorite-at-uw-parkside/article_61c91fac-062c-11e4-95f6-0019bb2963f4.html) for a UW history professor that features some personal comments from Cashion. And then there is [this travel account](https://cdr.lib.unc.edu/indexablecontent/uuid:eb815b21-0061-4993-82f2-f1f4169c74de?dl=true) (downloads a .doc file!) that mentions some personal anecdotes about Cashion.

Comment: @Anyon very interesting! Did you know him as "Ken"? When I searched "JK Cashion" I found almost nothing in terms of biographical information: Polanyi's website briefly mentioned him, but didn't reveal his first or middle names, and it was by digging through papers found on Google Scholar that I was able to find where he worked (and who he worked with), and then eventually after having spent a lot of time writing this post, I found that a BibTeX entry from Google Scholar for his PhD thesis gave the full name, but searching "John Cashion" or "John K Cashion" didn't provide much more than JK did.

Comment: Well, I don't think I've ever met the man, so probably I first read or heard "Ken Cashion" in some account about the discovery of chemiluminescence.

Comment: @Anyon Cool! You had an advantage over me in that you'd heard or seen him as "Ken" rather than "JK" or "John". I looked up "Ken Cashion" on Google just now and still it wasn't until the 20th hit (last hit on the 2nd page; i.e. I had to click "next" once, and still scroll to the bottom) that his University of Wisconsin page came up (the first 19 of them for me didn't seem to be about him). That page also didn't have any biographical information, so your searching was still impressive! Interestingly the Polanyi website linked in my post only mentioned "JK Cashion" once, but yours has Ken 3 times

Answer (score 0):

## VibRot in MOLCAS doesn't find all levels

[bug](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug), [molcas](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molcas), [spectroscopy](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spectroscopy), [vibrations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vibrations), [software-assistance](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-assistance)

The (7,7) isotopologue of the *b*-state of Li<sub>2</sub> supports over 90 vibrational levels, as you can see from Table IV of my [2015 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.07184), or [lines 506 to 607 of the output](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/LEVEL/blob/9f7f3b59a6dae1e3a2a12989127bef62af7b865e/LEVEL_2022/test_suite/2015_Li2_b-state/Li2b_transformedIntegrationVariable.9#L506-#L999) of   my LEVEL program (the corresponding *input* can be found on lines 365 to 467 of [this file](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/LEVEL/blob/9f7f3b59a6dae1e3a2a12989127bef62af7b865e/LEVEL_2022/test_suite/2015_Li2_b-state/Li2b_transformedIntegrationVariable.5#L365-#L999)).

Using the `VibRot` program in OpenMOLCAS, I was only able to find about 80 vibrational levels (see [here for an output file that contains a printout of the input file at the top](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/LEVEL/blob/c0e9097551124dfaf4d9ce0705bd51d524ee1fac/LEVEL_2022/test_suite/2015_Li2_b-state/vibrot.log)). Using the `Scale` keyword didn't change things. The range (from `0.3` to `3000` in a.u.) of internuclear distances for numerical integration already has an extremely low lower bound and extremely high upper bound, and the `Step` value (`Step = 0.000000001` a.u.) for energies is already extremely low. Changing the `Range` or the `Step` values also didn't improve things. I'll be more specific:

- Increasing the lower bound of the integration range from `0.3` to `0.4` (ironically, since an increase in the lower bound should make the numerical solution less accurate) gave me 2 more vibrational levels, but increasing it further to `0.5` or `0.6` didn't give me more levels.
- Decreasing the upper bound of the integration range from `3000` to `1000` gave me fewer levels, but increasing it to `4000` caused the program to crash prematurely and making it `3500` also gave me fewer levels. I could try `2000` and other values but the calculations take extremely long (for a rovibrational solver) and this type of trial-and-error work is unusual for trying to find over a dozen missing levels (perhaps I need to explicitly incorporate the C<sub>3</sub>/r<sup>3</sup> long-range tail of the potential like LEVEL does?).
- Strangely, increasing the `Grid` value usually made the numerical solution worse (leading to more convergence problems and/or fewer vibrational energies found). For example, the above-linked output file shows that I used `Grid = 470` and when using `500` I got marginally more levels, but when using `Grid = 510` the program found fewer levels again.
- Decreasing `Step` surprisingly does reduce the number of levels (marginally) but increasing it would make the cost outrageously long for the standards of a rovibrational level solver (the runtime is already extremely long with the `Step` value in the above calculation).

**Is it possible with `VibRot` to get a number of vibrational levels closer to what the above-linked LEVEL output gave me (which was 98 vibrational levels including $v=0$)?**

Answer (score 0):

## Can this procedure for multiply augmenting a basis set with the "basis_set_exchange" package be improved?

[python](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python),[basis-sets](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basis-sets),[basis-set-exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basis-set-exchange),[quantum-chemistry](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry),[electronic-structure](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-structure)

#### 1) Install the `basis_set_exchange` package

`git clone` and `pip install -e` are required because the default version that's installed with `pip` does not include the `basis_set_exchange.manip.geometric_augmentation()` function for multiply augmenting a basis set:

```
git clone https://github.com/MolSSI-BSE/basis_set_exchange.git
pip install -e basis_set_exchange
```

#### 2) Create a basis set "dictionary" for the original basis set

We will multiply augment the `aug-cc-pVDZ` basis set for the `H` atom. We can also do it for other atoms by using something like `elements=[6,8]` or even `elements=['C', 8, 'Ne', '16']`:

```
bs_dict = basis_set_exchange.get_basis('aug-cc-pVDZ',elements=1)
```

#### 3) Add the extra diffuse functions:

The `1` indicates that we're constructing a `daug` basis set, but we could use `2` and get a `taug` basis set, or `3` and get a `qaug` basis set:

```
daug=basis_set_exchange.manip.geometric_augmentation(bs_dict, 1, use_copy=True, as_component=False, steep=False)
```

#### 4) Get the new basis set into the format we desire

In this case I'll use the Guassian basis set format:

```
daug_in_gaussian_format=basis_set_exchange.write_formatted_basis_str(daug, 'gaussian94', header=None)
```

#### 4) Print the new basis set to a file!

```
print(daug_in_gaussian_format,  file=open('daug-cc-pVDZ.gbs', 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is nstate=6 invalid for a CIS calculation on the Ne atom with all 10 electrons correlated in a 6-31G basis set? The following works:

```
# TITLE
basis=6-31G-EMSL
uncontract=off
#iface=cfour
itol=18
scftol=12
cctol=5
calc=CC(9)
#mem=276GB
mem=8GB
core=corr
ccmaxit=999
scfmaxit=9999
scftype=RHF

scfiguess=ao
rohftype=standard
mult=1
charge=+0
rest=2
#symm = 7

unit=bohr
geom
Ne

#R=1.401100  # ! from Puchalsi2017, au.

tprint=0.01
verbosity=5
nstate=9
```

but not if nstate=6 or higher. There seems to be 3 s-contractions and 2 p-contractions. If an occupied electron is allowed to jump from 2p to 3s or 3p, and if the 1s and 2s electrons are allowed to jump from 3s or 3p, that would make 6 possible types of single excitations, plus a ground state (7 states).

Answer (score 0):

How can I get this paper? "F. B. van Duijneveldt, IBM Res. Rep. RJ 945 (1971)." The most cited paper by Dunning says that the cc-pVXZ basis sets for H were built on top of the Duijneveldt work:

[image]

For non-H there seems to be a typo in which Ref 26 refers to Ref 26:

[image]

Comment: PDF at https://dominoweb.draco.res.ibm.com/reports/RJ945.pdf The index for IBM's research reports is here: https://dominoweb.draco.res.ibm.com/index.html

Comment: Wow thanks @Anyon ! I didn't know anyone looked here, so these were just "draft" questions that I was going to ask after making them more presentable!

Comment: I don't know how many would look here to be honest. I just checked the meta and saw this at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Why no ^1S excited states of the Neon atom?

I see this:

```
[nike@cedar1 3z]$ grep "Excitation energy" ../5z/out.61410203 
 Excitation energy [eV]:          25.9781
 Excitation energy [cm^-1]:   209527.48
```

See this: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1797771
and this: https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/energy1.pl?de=0&spectrum=Ne+I&submit=Retrieve+Data&units=0&format=0&output=0&page_size=15&multiplet_ordered=0&conf_out=on&term_out=on&level_out=on&unc_out=1&j_out=on&lande_out=on&perc_out=on&biblio=on&temp=

Answer (score 0):

## For what things are molecular orbital coefficients used?

Answer (score 0):

## What are the seminal papers for ERIs?

- 1950 Boys

##### Based on the Rys quadrature:

- 1976,1983 Dupuis, Rys, and King x2 (Rys quadrature)
- 1978 Pople and Hehre (uses Rys quadrature, good for highly contracted s and p functions)
- 1986, 1988 Obara and Saika x 3 (reduce FLOPS by recurrence relation)
- 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991 Gill, Head-Gordon and Pople x 4 (reduce FLOPS, contraction scheme, "horizontal transfer equations")
- 1991, 1993 Lindh, Ryu, and Liu x2 (OS and GHP are less efficient than DRK when there's not much contraction)
- 1991,1996 Ishida x 2 (ACE has "attractive" FLOPS)
- 2001 [Dupuis and Marquez](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1336541) (combination of the above to optimize FLOPS) [**implementable!** but notation isn't familiar to all]
- 2004 Valeev libint
- 2014 Sun (libcint, uses DRK algorithm)
- 2014 Schwenke
- 2015 Shizgal
- 2016 King

##### Based on the McMurchie-Davidson scheme

- 1978 McMurchie Davidson (angular momentum transfer)
- 2022 Neese (SHARK) [**implementable!**]

##### Independent/largely-unnoticed

- 2018 Milovanovic

##### Parallelization and hardware-related optimizations

- 1994 Blelloch *et al.*
- 2007 Yasuda
- 2010 Asadschev *et al.*
- 2011 Luehr *et al.*
- 2012 Asadchev and Gordon
- 2013 Titove *et al.*

##### Reviews

- 1994 M. W. Gill,Adv. Quantum Chem.1994,25, 141.
- 2002 R. Lindh, in Encylopedia Comp Chem (Ed: P. von Rague-Schleyer), JohnWiley & Sons, Chichester
- 2018 Samu (PhD thesis, notation still complicated) [PDF](https://repozitorium.omikk.bme.hu/bitstream/handle/10890/13125)/ertekezes.pdf

Answer (score 0):

## Why has GW100 activity decreased?

Similar to this question: https://or.stackexchange.com/q/2869/727

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Why not just use STO-3G? Are the SAD projections from the first contracted functions of cc-pVTZ a better initial geuss than from STO-3G?

The best initial guess is probably from what MOLPRO calls `minao` which is STO-3G (converge an SCF calculation for STO-3G then use the densities for the initial guess for a bigger basis set).

Answer (score 0):

Which program is best for geometry optimization at CCSD(T) level?

Answer (score 0):

### Why is more RAM used when less RAM is available?

```
[nike@cedar5 6-31g]$ seff -d 64118367
Slurm data: JobID ArrayJobID User Group State Clustername Ncpus Nnodes Ntasks Reqmem PerNode Cput Walltime Mem ExitStatus
Slurm data: 64118367  nike nike TIMEOUT cedar 16 1 1 512000000 1 538932 42015 78222756 0

Job ID: 64118367
Cluster: cedar
User/Group: nike/nike
State: TIMEOUT (exit code 0)
Nodes: 1
Cores per node: 16
CPU Utilized: 6-05:42:12
CPU Efficiency: 80.17% of 7-18:44:00 core-walltime
Job Wall-clock time: 11:40:15
Memory Utilized: 74.60 GB
Memory Efficiency: 15.28% of 488.28 GB
```

versus:

```
[nike@cedar5 6-31g]$ seff -d 64116684
Slurm data: JobID ArrayJobID User Group State Clustername Ncpus Nnodes Ntasks Reqmem PerNode Cput Walltime Mem ExitStatus
Slurm data: 64116684  nike nike TIMEOUT cedar 16 1 1 258048000 1 203941 42006 239775292 0

Job ID: 64116684
Cluster: cedar
User/Group: nike/nike
State: TIMEOUT (exit code 0)
Nodes: 1
Cores per node: 16
CPU Utilized: 2-08:39:01
CPU Efficiency: 30.34% of 7-18:41:36 core-walltime
Job Wall-clock time: 11:40:06
Memory Utilized: 228.67 GB
Memory Efficiency: 92.92% of 246.09 GB
```

64118367:

```
cycle = 22  E_corr(CCSD) = -2.96983024494516  dE = -7.17617663e-08  norm(t1,t2) = 6.14803e-07
    CPU time for CCSD iter   7277.51 sec, wall time    825.65 sec
    CPU time for CCSD 159964.27 sec, wall time  18131.68 sec
UCCSD converged
E(UCCSD) = -2201.596863388799  E_corr = -2.96983024494516  
    CPU time for transpose 0:109      5.99 sec, wall time      3.77 sec
    CPU time for transpose 0:109      6.00 sec, wall time      3.73 sec
    CPU time for transpose 0:109      5.95 sec, wall time      3.69 sec
    CPU time for transpose 0:109      8.51 sec, wall time      3.74 sec
    CPU time for UCCSD(T) sort_eri     34.90 sec, wall time     23.60 sec
max_memory 438952 MB (61047 MB in use)
    CPU time for contract 0:109,0:109 145336.40 sec, wall time   9092.99 sec
    CPU time for contract_aaa 145336.40 sec, wall time   9093.04 sec
max_memory 438952 MB (61047 MB in use)
    CPU time for contract 0:109,0:109 144941.54 sec, wall time   9066.03 sec
    CPU time for contract_bbb 144941.55 sec, wall time   9066.10 sec

slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 64118367 ON cdr462 CANCELLED AT 2023-04-03T17:00:32 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
```

64116684:

```
DIIS for step 15
cycle = 16  E_corr(CCSD) = -2.98523291832199  dE = 3.54967027e-06  norm(t1,t2) = 1.33529e-05
    CPU time for CCSD iter  12179.50 sec, wall time   2554.15 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [0:28]      7.28 sec, wall time      1.60 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [28:56]     18.58 sec, wall time      1.23 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [56:84]     32.12 sec, wall time      2.11 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [84:109]     39.04 sec, wall time      2.54 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [0:28]      6.99 sec, wall time      1.54 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [28:56]     18.19 sec, wall time      1.20 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [56:84]     30.35 sec, wall time      2.00 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [84:109]     38.38 sec, wall time      2.49 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [0:28]     13.16 sec, wall time      3.01 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [28:56]     33.24 sec, wall time      2.15 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [56:84]     58.45 sec, wall time      3.83 sec
    CPU time for vvvv [84:109]     72.32 sec, wall time      4.66 sec

slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 64116684 ON cdr994 CANCELLED AT 2023-04-03T15:48:31 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
```

Files:

````
/nike/polyat/100-atoms_GW5000/pyscf/sto-3g
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## Which software supports non-Abelian point groups?

Answer (score 0):

In [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S000926149900247X?via%3Dihub) it says that they use 3 bond lengths, 2 bond angles and 1 dihedral:

[image]

However, we only need 2 bond lengths, 1 bond angle, and 1 dihedral:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Is dCache used in Matter Modeling?

> "dCache: dCache is a storage filesystem developed originally for high-energy physics projects for very large datasets (petabytes). dCache storage is essentially an object file storage layer on top of classical storage providing a single namespace and various authorized access and transfer protocols to the underlying immutable data. Allocations here tend to be for large projects with many Principal Investigators and researchers. dCache capacity is allocated via the RAC process. If you wish to use this storage, contact the Subatomic Physics National Team by writing to our Technical support. "